# Fourier Transform Commutes Derivatives

Tags: derivatives, fourier-transform, convolution

Consider two integrable functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, whose derivatives (and higher order derivatives) are also integrable. Note that $f, g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. From the properties of the Fourier transform (and convolutions), the Fourier transform of the product $\frac{df}{dx}\, g(x)$ is

$$
\begin{align*}
 \mathcal{F}\left[\frac{df}{dx}\, g(x)\right](\omega) &= \mathcal{F}\left[\frac{df}{dx}\right](\omega) * \mathcal{F}\left[g(x)\right](\omega) \\
     &= \left(2\,\pi\,i\,\omega\,\mathcal{F}\left[f(x)\right](\omega)\right) * \mathcal{F}\left[g(x)\right](\omega) \\
     &= 2\,\pi\,i\,\omega\,\left(\mathcal{F}\left[f(x)\right](\omega) * \mathcal{F}\left[g(x)\right](\omega)\right) \\
     &= 2\,\pi\,i\,\omega\,\left(\mathcal{F}\left[g(x)\right](\omega) * \mathcal{F}\left[f(x)\right](\omega)\right) \\
     &= \left(2\,\pi\,i\,\omega\,\mathcal{F}\left[g(x)\right](\omega)\right) * \mathcal{F}\left[f(x)\right](\omega) \\
     &= \mathcal{F}\left[\frac{dg}{dx}\right](\omega)* \mathcal{F}\left[f(x)\right](\omega) \\
     &= \mathcal{F}\left[f(x)\right](\omega) * \mathcal{F}\left[\frac{dg}{dx}\right](\omega) \\
     &= \mathcal{F}\left[f(x)\,\frac{dg}{dx}\right](\omega),
\end{align*}
$$

where $*$ specifies convolution.

Taking the inverse transform of both sides, we see that $\frac{df}{dx}\, g(x) = f(x)\,\frac{dg}{dx}$ which is obviously wrong. The issue is that I don't see what's wrong with the argument? The only thing I can think of is the integrability of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and their derivatives.

---

For context, I have been working with finite difference and pseudo-spectral methods, and wanted to investigate the Fourier transform of the Jacobian operator $J(f(x, y), g(x, y)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$.

Comment: That * means convolution, not multiplication. You seem to use the identity $(\omega F(\omega))*G(\omega)=F(\omega)*(\omega G(\omega))$, which you just made up with no justification.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response!

Yes, $*$ means convolution, I should have specified. From the [Wikipedia article on convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Properties), your statement follows from the commutativity of convolution and the associativity of convolution with scalar multiplication. Specifically,

$$
\begin{align*}
(\omega\,F(\omega)) * G(\omega) &= \omega\,(F(\omega) * G(\omega)) \\
     &= \omega\,(G(\omega) * F(\omega) \\
     &= (\omega\,G(\omega)) * F(\omega) \\
     &= F(\omega) * (\omega\,G(\omega)).
\end{align*}
$$

At least, I think that works?

Comment: @jltorchinsky : If you don't tag \@DavidC.Ullrich in your comment, he won't be notified that it exists.  Also, why do you believe the variable $\omega$ is a scalar?

Comment: Ah, thanks @EricTowers! I figure $\omega$ is a scalar since the argument for each of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is a scalar (which I should have specified!). Is that incorrect?

@DavidC.Ullrich Thank you for your response! Please see my response above.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is a scalar, not depending on $\omega$ then
$$\begin{align*} (\lambda\,F(\omega)) * G(\omega) &= \lambda\,(F(\omega) * G(\omega)) \\      &= \lambda\,(G(\omega) * F(\omega) \\      &= (\lambda\,G(\omega)) * F(\omega) \\      &= F(\omega) * (\lambda\,G(\omega)). \end{align*}$$
but for $\lambda=\omega$ it is not valid.

Comment: @md2perpe Ah, I see! The "associativity of convolution with scalar multiplication" only applies to scalars which are independent of $\omega$, is that what you're saying?

Thank you for your response!

Comment: That's what I say. Convolution is an operation on a linear/vector space of functions where scalars are (constant) numbers; they may not be functions that vary over the domain.